# Table joined to a layer doesn't appear when uploaded to web map

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a layer in my map to which I’ve joined an Excel spreadsheet that shows additional attributes.

Once the join was successful, I exported the joined layer to my map’s file geodatabase and added it back to my map.

From there I wanted to upload this joined layer to a web map (“share as a map service”) which should automatically update the web map application, but the extra fields from the join are not visible.

Is there a reason why this is occurring? Is there a suitable workaround?

Comment: I don't think the joined attributes are saved as part of the attribute table; try exporting the joined data to a new file from within ArcMap, that might also save the joined data, but I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is because joined data doesn't get exported along with the main data. Or rather, it exports just fine, but the relevant joined file (your excel sheet) will not be accessible from the web, so they end up missing.

There's two solutions offered by the ArcGIS manual to make joins permanent, both work fine:

- Export your layer to a featureclass (this makes the joined attributes permanent)
  or
- use the "Join Field" tool, which also will write the attributes into your layer permanently instead of just linking them (which is what a regular join is supposed to do).

Answer (score 0):

Joined data is not supported when you publish the layer to ArcGIS Online or Portal (see this [page](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/author-feature-services.htm)). You would have to [create a relationship class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/relationships/an-overview-of-creating-and-maintaining-relationsh.htm).